# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorboard'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

```
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
```

Not sure what the issue is here, here are my packages

[image]

And the others

[image]

Cuda toolkit is at 10.1.243

When I use

```
%load_ext tensorboard
```

It returns

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorboard'

Comment: downgraded to TF 1.15, and fixed the issue.

Comment: this worked for me: `conda install -y -c conda-forge tensorboard` btw if you are using pytorch it seems you need to install that yourself too although pytorch does not say it clearly in their tutorial (or at all).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Do  `pip install tensorboard` 
this will solve your problem

Comment: If I've been using Anaconda, would this be incompatible?

Comment: no am using anaconda too , and it helped

Comment: This command should be written in project directory, or else you will get an error about virtual environment. Tested with PyCharm and virtual environment (witch is default since python 3.4)

Answer (score 7):

this worked for me:

```
conda install -y -c conda-forge tensorboard
```

btw if you are using pytorch it seems you need to install that yourself too although pytorch does not say it clearly in their tutorial (or at all).

Comment: It just waits forever in `Solving environment...`

Comment: Alright, it's just a long wait... about half an hour or less.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are launching `%load_ext tensorboard`, I guess you are working in a notebook.

If that's the case before doing anything, I will check if tensorboard is installed. If you previously launched a `model.fit()` with a tensorboard callback, then I guess it is installed, but you can try launching it from the terminal with `tensorboard --logdir tb_log`.

In my case it was working, so TB was installed. My issue was that after the in the notebook my command was: `tensorboard --logdir tb_log # some commment as with python` . After removing the comment an any other extra space, TB was launched.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; these are the steps I took to solve it (BTW, others have already pointed to different solutions above that also work). I assume that You are working from Jupyter notebook and trying to access the GUI tensorboard for the graphs and scalars:

## In terminal:

```
pip install tensorboard
```

## In your Jupyter notebook:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard 
logdir = os.path.join("logs", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")) 

tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq =  1, write_graph = True,write_images = True)
```

## Then you can access any element within the GUI, e.g.,:

```
%tensorboard --logdir logs/scalars
```